# DynamoDBContext does not have Save() method

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I'm new to AWS server less programming. 
I'm trying to following sample using server less architecture.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.ArbitraryDataMapping.html

But I couldn't find Save() method in DynamoDBContext class, it only contains SaveAsync(). Could anyone tell me why is that?

Comment: Have you checked that you have the latest version of the AWS library?

Comment: @TrentBartlem Yes, I have check with the latest version. I believe serverless lambda application can not use normal methods to communicate with DuynamoDB, thus I'm had to use SaveAsync().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have check with the latest version. I believe serverless lambda application can not use normal methods to communicate with DynamoDB, thus I'm had to use SaveAsync(). –

Answer (score 0):

> The reason the .NET Core version only has async is because the underlying http client available in .NET Core only supports async operations. We debated about keeping the sync methods in the .NET Core version and have them just call the async versions and then block. The problem with that is the SDK would not be following best practice for the platform and more importantly it could mask a potential performance problem.
>
> https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/480#issuecomment-257382757

AWS team recommends:

```
public async Task<Response> ProcessS3ImageResizeAsync(SimpleS3Event input)
{
   var response = await client.DoAsyncWork(input);
   return response;
}
```

more details at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html#dot-net-async